# Can I use CASE statement in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

**EDITED**

---

I want to check one condition if another condition true else not

```
 DECLARE @id INT= 1;

 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE1
  WHERE ETID = CASE  
          WHEN ID = @id THEN 
            1 
          ELSE 
            @id = 0 
        END
```

Comment: This is not a question, please complete it.

Comment: Please delete the question and ask again with detail information as much as you can.

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: It seems that you want `where (EtId = 1) and (Id = @id) or (EtId = 0) and (@id = 0)` or alike condition

Comment: you can use 'or' in where clause

Comment: The problem is that we can't read your mind. So what do you want to achieve? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Also, we don't know what data is in your database and therefore what the possible results are. Info like that is needed to come up with a good answer. Be complete. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but most likely not needed.

```
DECLARE @id INT= 1;

 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE1
  WHERE ETID = 
        CASE  
          WHEN ID = @id THEN 1 
          WHEN @id = 0  THEN ...
          WHEN ...
          ELSE ...
        END
```

Alternative solution

```
DECLARE @id INT= 1;

 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE1
  WHERE    (ID = @id and ETID = 1)
        or (@id = 0 ...)
        or ...
```

Comment: See if that answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineering:

> I want to check one condition if another condition true else not

```
    WHERE ETID = CASE  
            WHEN ID = @id THEN 
              1 
            ELSE 
             @id = 0 
          END
```

Let's reconstruct the actual condition (at least try doing this):

```
  if (ID = @id) then 
    if (ETID = 1) then 
      obtain record
  else if (ID != @id) -- "else" in case
    obtain record -- want to check one condition...else NOT
```

then let's write where:

```
 select *
   from Table1
  where (ID = @id) and (ETID = 1) or -- check one condition if another condition true...
        (ID <> @id)                  -- ...else not
```

However, since the question is *very vague* some other variants are possible, e.g.:

```
 select *
   from Table1
  where (ID = @id) and (ETID = 1) or -- check one condition if another condition true...
        (ETID <> 1)                  -- ...else not
```

according to what *one condition* and *another condition* mean